# Jquery ~ Function, just working with alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, alert

I have the following function that is actually working on Chrome and Firefox, but its´not working in Internet Explorer

```
$(".info").on("click", function(e){
        //alert("Message");
        if(tp==0){
            fila[0]=$(this).children();
            fila[1]=$(this).children().slice(0,2);
            var x = $(this).children().children().children().attr('title');

            var tot="<td colspan='7' style='font-size:22px;'>"+x+"</td>";
            $(this).html(fila[1][0]);
            $(this).append(fila[1][1]);
            $(this).append("<td colspan='7' style='font-size:22px;'>"+x+"</td>");
        }
        tp=1;
    });
```

I make it works on IE if the alert line is uncommented like this:

```
$(".info").on("click", function(e){
        alert("Message");
        if(tp==0){
            fila[0]=$(this);
            fila[1]=$(this).slice(0,2);
            var x = $(this).attr('title');

            var tot="<td colspan='7' style='font-size:22px;'>"+x+"</td>";
            $(this).html(fila[1][0]);
            $(this).append(fila[1][1]);
            $(this).append("<td colspan='7' style='font-size:22px;'>"+x+"</td>");
        }
        tp=1;
    });
```

The question is, how can I make it works without this alert on IE?
Sorry for my bad English.

For those that ask me, here is where I def my "tp"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var pedidos_carritos = [];
     var linea = [];
     var cont;
     var aux=0;
     var tp=0;
     var fila =[];
```

Comment: What is `tp` and where is it defined?

Comment: do not put `//any comments` within `code`

Comment: try giving it as `$(document).on("click",".info", function(e){`

Comment: any script error in IE

Comment: Add `var tp = 0` just before `$(".info").on("click", function(e){` and try

Comment: tp is just a variable that allows me to controll if it´s the first time that I ran this function or not. @ArunPJohny

Comment: Nope, console clear @ArunPJohny

Comment: Same error btw @GuruprasadRao

Comment: if I add {var tp=0} it works, so I think the problem is that IE isn´t recognizing this lane after my {<script>} tag @ArunPJohny

Comment: I mean, it works if I type `var tp = 0` inside the function, not in otherwise, @ArunPJohny

Answer (score 0):

Just put console.log("your message") instead of an alert and check if it works.
I am not sure.

Comment: I have already tried this, it displays "message" in the console, but still don´t working

Answer (score 0):

Until you can fix this in IE, you need to know which line of code isn't working. You've only put your alert in one place. Try putting it AFTER the if statement and then try every line after that until you can pinpoint it down.

You could also step through in the debugger, but above will be easier if you have never done this.

Is this code at the bottom of the page / in a document ready function?

Comment: Well, the truth is that no one line is failing for real (already debugged it), I can place the alert in every line, and It keeps on working, the problem is when it doesn´t appear.

Comment: This code is at the `<script>` tag at the bottom of the page.

Comment: If it's performing each line, then tp is a red herring.

I would be more likely to suggest an issue with IE manipulating the HTML.

Rather than using .html - why not create a whole new node and use replaceWith instead, once it's ready to be deployed?